# What are advantages with or without of using position:static; in css?

Tags: html, css

I have doubts in css position according to `position:static;` value.

I can find about static, that is,

The value static is the default, or initial value, for the position property.

This means that, if you don’t declare a position value on an element, it starts out as “static”.

So what does this value mean in terms of the element’s behavior?

I can used in practical, there is nothing change in my web page.

So what is the advantage to use static value, and if i am not using static value, Is there any issue i meet?

Please clarify to this question, thanks in advance.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/what-if-there-was-no-position-static/

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say, `static` is default, so in most cases you don't need to specify it. Adding `position: static` that is already positioned static doesn't change a thing.

But you can use static to revert another style to default. For instance, if you want all `div`s to be positioned relatively, except for those with a specific class, you can write this:

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

div.aspecificclass {
  position: static;
}
```

So that's probably the reason why `static` and all those other default values can still be specified in CSS.

Comment: Trol: thanks for your answer, may i know when i can use inherit value?

Comment: Yes. You use `inherit` when you want the value to be the same as for the parent element.

Comment: thanks @golez. if i didn't use position:inherit; for the child element, what will happen?

Comment: Then it would keep the value it had. The default value differs per element and per property, but you can `inspect element` and using the developer tools of the browser, you can inspect what value a property for an element has.

Comment: ok.. and may i know, what is your point about static vs inherit?

Comment: I must admit, I've hardly ever had to use either `static` or `inherit` for position. And if I do, it depends on the situation. I don't have a general preference for either.